# iPhone address book - get phone number as string with numbers only

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, number-formatting, phone-number

I am getting a phone number from the address book and I put it in an NSString* :

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person,property);
NSString *phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty,identifier);
```

I want to get only the numbers as a straight string (meaning without characters like (,),+,- and so on).

when I execute the code above and check it `NSLog(@"phone is %@", phone);` I get: `phone is 1 (800) 800-8000`

Actually In the Xcode console I see that before the '(' and after the ')' there is a centre dot sign which was not copied properly to this post.

My goal is to turn `1 (800) 800-8000` to this `18008008000`. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but keep in mind that there are many different formats if you intend to support localization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
NSString *filtered = [[phone componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
    [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                                         componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in so many ways.

One simple way:

```
NSString *phone = @"1 (800) 800-8000 home";
NSString *strippedNumber = [phone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [phone length])];
```

**Note:** `[^0-9]` means *any characters apart from `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, or `9`*.